# Could not find or load main class org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I am not able to compile an individual JSP file, however if I compile whole project it is compiled without error.

```
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle
F:\java projs\test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: How did you compile it ?

Comment: right click on the editor.. runfile

Comment: see this [thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38755.html) it might help you